# get cell value from dgrid inside of custom widget onclick

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a custom widget with a dgrid inside and would like to grab the cell value when the cell is clicked.  Heres an excerpt of my widget code:

```
...
 postCreate: function () {
...
 grid.on(".field-Ticket:click", lang.hitch(grid, this.markTicket));

},
markTicket: function () {
//how can I get value of the cell that was clicked?
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Working with Events](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.3.15/doc/usage/Working-with-Events.md) in the dgrid docs. The click event handler gets a regular click event, but dgrid has a `cell()` method giving you the cell object that was clicked, based on the event object.

From that, you can get the column, row etc:

```js
markTicket: function (clickEvent) {
    var cell = grid.cell(clickEvent);
    alert("You clicked " + cell.row.data.Ticket);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem I'm having is passing the click event from postCreate function to the markTicket function. I'm trying using the code below but it nots working:
grid.on(".field-Ticket:click", lang.hitch(grid, this.markTicket(evt)));

Comment: Nevermind, I see that your solution works now -- I dont pass the event to the function on the postcreate when I do the hitch
Thanks

Comment: @pvitt You can use hitch, but of course you have to do `grid.on(".field-Ticket:click", lang.hitch(grid, this.markTicket));`. Remember that calling a function: `someFunction()` is not the same as a function reference: `someFunction`. When you have the parenthesis after the function name, you actually execute it.